# Find duplicates that appear exactly twice in a list

Tags: c#, lambda, find

I have a list that is automatically generated

```
var v = new List<int>(1000);
var generateur = new Random(1);
for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
     v.Add(generateur.Next(10000));
```

And I want to find how many number repeat exactly twice using only one `lambda expression`.

Comment: Now we now what you want. What have you tried to get that? :)

Comment: int nbValeurDouble = v.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 2);

Comment: I am pretty new to programming and find it pretty hard to do it in only one expression :P

Comment: Group by Count() and you're done.

Comment: Try this `var newlist= v.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 2).Select(j=>j.Key).ToList();`

Comment: _how many_ means a count of the numbers that appear two times and not a list of these numbers right?

Comment: yes, not a list but the number of times

Comment: If you want the number of duplicates, as @Steve rightly points out, would be something like `var number= v.GroupBy(i => i).Where(g => g.Count() == 2).Count();`

Comment: Thanks to you all ! This is my first question on Stack how can I upvote your comments ?

Comment: You can do it with the up arrow that appears when you hover a comment left side. But the most important thing is to accept an answer, you have 3 to choose :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question (and the integer that you use as result in your code comment) it seems that you want to Count the number of times a group of two numbers appears. Not a list of these numbers.

Then the solution is

```
 int repeated = v.GroupBy(x => x).Where(g => g.Count() == 2).Count();
```

Comment: I think you're correct Steve I interpreted it as returning a list of those that repeated vs a total count but after re-reading it your solution is most correct `+2`

Comment: @MethodMan Initially I was thinking on the same line and choosed your answer as the correct one (no dupe) and going on another question, but then relooking at his comment I notice the detail.

Comment: I can get the same thing if I add the following to allow the OP 2 alternatives 1 to return a list of what numbers were in the list exactly 2 times or return a total count of how many duplicates were in the list exactly 2 times .. see my additional update as well

Comment: This can be shortened to `v.GroupBy(x => x).Count(g => g.Count() == 2);`

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> listDup = new List<String> { "6", "1", "2", "4", "6", "5", "1" };
var duplicates = listDup.GroupBy(n => n)
                 .Where(grp => grp.Count() == 2)
                 .Select(grp => grp.Key).ToList();
```

Yields a list containing 6 and 1 since these show up exactly twice in the list.

using the above code to get a total count of items that were in the list 2 times

```
int count2Times = listNonDup.GroupBy(x => x).Where(x => x.Count() == 2).Count();
```